# What environment does an application run in if started via desktop shortcut?

Tags: linux, desktop, shortcuts, environment-variables, linux-mint

I have noticed that the environment variables I export in my `.profile` or `.bashrc` files are not available to applications started via a desktop shortcut. At least to my IDE.
They are available if I start it from terminal.

Do I really have to modify `/etc/profile` to make the variables accessible to every program? I would prefer having them user-specific. I am sure there's a better way, but I lack the experience.

I am running Mint 11.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gnome runs a startup script in `~/.gnomerc` at login time.  If you add any env variables you want to this file, they should then be exposed to any desktop application you run.  This is then a user specific solution.